# Next.js Link tag fully reload page while navigating between pages after deployment

Tags: reactjs, next.js, netlify

### Hi!, I am new to next.js and I was making a website and I get into this really weird problem:

1. When I am in development server the Link tag of next.js did fine i.e. it navigates through pages without fully reloading the page but when i deploy the web on netlify while navigating through pages the page is fully reloading while navigating through pages

### [Link of Website after delpoyment](https://soft-peony-4dd2a9.netlify.app/)

I dont know why this is happening.

#### Seeking some help..

### Navbar.jsx

```
"use client"
import Image from 'next/image';
import logo from '../app/favicon.ico'
import Link from 'next/link';
const Navbar = () => {
    const toggleNavbar = () => {
        const menu = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu");
        menu.classList.toggle("hidden");
    }


    return (
        <nav className="bg-gray-900 fixed w-full z-50 top-0 left-0 border-b  border-gray-600 ">
            <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto p-2">
                <div className="flex justify-between">
                    <div>
                        <Link
                            href="./"
                            className="flex items-center"
                        >
                            <Image
                                src={logo} className="h-12 mr-3 rounded-full"
                                alt="fsu logo"
                                width={50}
                            />
                            <span
                                className="self-center text-2xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap text-white">
                                FSU
                            </span>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-1 gap-8 navLinksMd">
                        <Link
                            href="/"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Home
                        </Link>
                        <Link
                            href="/about"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            About
                        </Link>
                        <Link
                            href="/notices"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Notices
                        </Link>
                        <Link
                            href="/events"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Events
                        </Link>
                        <Link
                            href="/gallery"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Gallery
                        </Link>
                        <Link
                            href="/contact"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Contact
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="hidden md:flex items-center space-x-3 ">
                        <Link href="/complain">
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                className="text-white   focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none  font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-4 py-2 text-center mr-3 md:mr-0 bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:ring-blue-800"
                            >
                                Complain Box
                            </button>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="md:hidden flex items-center">
                        <button onClick={toggleNavbar} className="outline-none mobile-menu-button">
                            <svg className=" w-6 h-6 text-gray-500 hover:text-green-500 "
                                x-show="!showMenu"
                                fill="none"
                                strokeLinecap="round"
                                strokeLinejoin="round"
                                strokeWidth="2"
                                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                stroke="currentColor"
                            >
                                <path d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="hidden mobile-menu p-4">
                <ul className="">
                    <li
                        className='border-t border-b border-gray-700'
                        onClick={toggleNavbar}
                    >
                        <Link href="/"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded   md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Home
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li
                        className='border-b border-gray-700'
                        onClick={toggleNavbar}
                    >
                        <Link
                            href="/about"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded  md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            About
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li
                        className='border-b border-gray-700'
                        onClick={toggleNavbar}
                    >
                        <Link
                            href="/notices"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded   md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Notices
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li
                        className='border-b border-gray-700'
                        onClick={toggleNavbar}
                    >
                        <Link
                            href="/events"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded  md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Events
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li
                        className='border-b border-gray-700'
                        onClick={toggleNavbar}
                    >
                        <Link
                            href="/gallery"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded  md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Gallery
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li
                        className='border-b border-gray-700'
                        onClick={toggleNavbar}
                    >
                        <Link
                            href="/contact"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded  md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Contact Us
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li
                        className='border-b border-gray-700'
                        onClick={toggleNavbar}
                    >
                        <Link
                            href="/complain"
                            className="block py-2 pl-3 pr-4 rounded  md:p-0 md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 text-white "
                        >
                            Complain Box
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

### next.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        domains: [
            'scontent.fbir1-1.fna.fbcdn.net',
            'beforeigosolutions.com',
            'i.ibb.co'
        ],
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

### jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried on development server every time but it works absolutely fine but after deployment doesn't work.

Comment: It was because i deployed the website on netlify, I works fine when I deploy on vercel